# How does postgres store django choice_fields - getting column "type" of relation does not exist error

Tags: database, django, postgresql, django-models, choicefield

I have a CharField type with a choices field as follows:

```
class Thing(models.Model):
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

    A = 'a'
    B = 'b'
    C = 'c'

    TYPE_CHOICES = (
        (A, 'a'),
        (B, 'b'),
        (C, 'c'),
    )
        ...
    type = models.CharField(max_length = 1, choices=TYPE_CHOICES)
        ...
```

Now when I try to access a page add/thing I am getting a DatabaseError at /path/to/thing/add/
column "type" of relation "place_thing" does not exist

I checked the database (postgres), and I found that type was not a column as said in the error.

Why is the type field not being added when I sync or migrate the database?

How can I create the columns 'TYPE_CHOICES' and 'type' in my database (postgres)?

Can someone explain to me what would be created by the database for class Thing?

Thank you

katie

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using

ALTER TABLE table_name ADD COLUMN type varchar(30);

and this worked

i guess the TYPE_CHOICES column was already made

thanks

Comment: Do note that "type" can be a poor choice for a column name. http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-keywords-appendix.html